# Shapefile from group of FIPS codes

Tags: qgis, shapefile, fips

I am new to QGIS and GIS in general. I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
FIPS Code   Area Name   Area Description
10001       A1          D1
10002       A1          D1
10003       A2          D2 
10004       A2          D2
```

I want to create a vector layer or shapefile that will show boundaries for each Area based of FIPS codes that belong to that Area. I do not want to see county FIPS borders, just Area borders.

I have "wkt_geom" data for each FIPS. I extracted it from Counties Vector Layer from ESRI's website. It looks like this:

```
MultiPolygon (((-99.4097266969388329 28.63827052216430502, -100.11285992001091927 28.63845898525977418, -100.11502942137985883 29.08920919633010271, -99.41330138287827367 29.09272057773335973, -99.4097266969388329 28.63827052216430502)))
```

Not sure if this is helpful.

Comment: Do you have any spatial data to go along with your CSV?

Comment: Do you current see county FIPS borders from your CSV? Or just the table attribute you screenshot above?

Comment: Yes, I have another column from US Counties Vector Layer I downloaded from ArcGIS site. I can match it to my data on FIPS. It looks like this: wkt_geom
MultiPolygon (((-101.13538379946879786 44.74944522091215049, -101.21060139983171666 44.70310811353277813, -101.32636980358154233 44.68402360900051917...

Comment: When I add this data to QGIS as a new Vector Layer it just creates borders for each FIPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `dissolve` tool, which you can find in the Processing Toolbox. Use the "area name" field as the grouping field in the dissolve tool.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!